# Union SUM SQL Must have its own alias

Tags: sql, count, union

I have made some relative posts with the same errors, I have tried almost every solution that has been suggested.

**Here is the SQL:**

```
SELECT Sum(h.counter1 + l.counter2) AS hour_amount 
FROM   ( 
          SELECT 1 
          FROM   xp_hour h 
          WHERE  h.account_id = '1' 
          AND    h.hour_date = Date('2017-03-06') 
          AND    (( 
                               h.from_time < Time('06:00') 
                        AND    h.till_time > Time('06:00')) 
                 OR     ( 
                               h.from_time < Time('15:00') 
                        AND    h.till_time > Time('15:00')) 
                 OR     ( 
                               h.from_time = Time('06:00') 
                        AND    h.till_time = Time('15:00')))) 
UNION ALL 
      ( 
             SELECT 1 
             FROM   xp_leave l 
             WHERE  l.account_id = '1' 
             AND    (( 
                                  l.from_datetime < Timestamp('2017-03-06 06:00') 
                           AND    l.till_datetime > Timestamp('2017-03-06 06:00')) 
                    OR     ( 
                                  l.from_datetime < Timestamp('2017-03-06 15:00') 
                           AND    l.till_datetime > Timestamp('2017-03-06 15:00')))) t_union
```

**Error**

```
Error: Every derived table must have its own alias
```

Comment: I think if you just formatted your query you would have saved yourself a couple of hours.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT SUM(h.counter1 + l.counter2) AS hour_amount 
FROM (   
   SELECT 1 
   FROM xp_hour h 
   WHERE h.account_id = '1' AND h.hour_date = DATE('2017-03-06') AND 
         ( 
          (h.from_time < TIME('06:00') AND h.till_time > TIME('06:00')) OR 
          (h.from_time < TIME('15:00') AND h.till_time > TIME('15:00')) OR 
          (h.from_time = TIME('06:00') AND h.till_time = TIME('15:00'))
         )

   UNION ALL 

   SELECT 1 
   FROM xp_leave l 
   WHERE l.account_id = '1' AND 
       (
         (l.from_datetime < TIMESTAMP('2017-03-06 06:00') AND 
          l.till_datetime > TIMESTAMP('2017-03-06 06:00')) OR 
        (l.from_datetime < TIMESTAMP('2017-03-06 15:00') AND 
         l.till_datetime > TIMESTAMP('2017-03-06 15:00'))
       )
) t_union
```

You need to enclose the *whole* `UNION ALL` subquery in parentheses, not the individual subqueries that take part in the `UNION ALL` operation.

Answer (score 1):

Problem is with parenthesis. 1st query is interpreted as separate question which belongs to first from.

Try this:

```
SELECT SUM(h.counter1 + l.counter2) AS hour_amount FROM 
(SELECT 1 FROM xp_hour h WHERE h.account_id = '1' AND h.hour_date = DATE('2017-03-06') AND ((h.from_time < TIME('06:00') AND h.till_time > TIME('06:00')) OR (h.from_time < TIME('15:00') AND h.till_time > TIME('15:00')) OR (h.from_time = TIME('06:00') AND h.till_time = TIME('15:00'))) 
UNION ALL 
(SELECT 1 FROM xp_leave l WHERE l.account_id = '1' AND ((l.from_datetime < TIMESTAMP('2017-03-06 06:00') AND l.till_datetime > TIMESTAMP('2017-03-06 06:00')) OR (l.from_datetime < TIMESTAMP('2017-03-06 15:00') AND l.till_datetime > TIMESTAMP('2017-03-06 15:00'))))) t_union
```

I remove the last `)` from 1st query to end of `union`

Answer (score -1):

Name a alias for the first part of the derived table before `UNION ALL` like you put `t_union` for the 2nd part.

for example:

```
(SELECT 1 
FROM xp_hour h 
WHERE h.account_id = '1' 
AND h.hour_date = DATE('2017-03-06') 
AND ((h.from_time < TIME('06:00') 
AND h.till_time > TIME('06:00')) 
OR (h.from_time < TIME('15:00') 
AND h.till_time > TIME('15:00')) 
OR (h.from_time = TIME('06:00') 
AND h.till_time = TIME('15:00')))) as t_union_1
```